# Cmd+` breaks with dual monitors and full screen mode

Tags: macbook-pro, display, fullscreen

I want to run Chrome in full screen mode on both my monitors, using Cmd+` to alternate between windows. Cmd+` seems to work fine for alternating between windows when not in full screen mode, but it seems as though when I'm in full screen mode there's no way to do it, and my secondary windows are inaccessible.

The Q&A on this page states that it's "not possible": [Full screen mode in two monitors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71148/full-screen-mode-in-two-monitors)

Why is it "not possible". Surely Mac OS X is able to make a distinction between windows even when one of them is in full screen mode. And if by putting a window in full screen mode it is able to leave the second monitor showing other applications, then it must have some awareness of other displays that can display other windows.

UPDATE: I'm running Mavericks.

Comment: I just tried and works fine for me. I could open two full screen chrome windows on different monitor, no problem at all. I also could switch between then with ⌘+`, again without issues there. I'm running Yosemite, the post you mention is talking about mountain lion.

Comment: What OS X version are you on? In Yosemite, there's no visual feedback, but you can still switch. Before Mavericks, there was only one menu bar, spaces were coordinated for all monitors, and it was impossible to have more than one window fullscreen at a time.

Comment: makes me miss my windows :/