# Cmd-` with full-screen windows on one monitor

Tags: macos, fullscreen, shortcut

<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> switches between windows of the active app, but it doesn't work if the windows are full-screen.

According to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154673/cmd-breaks-with-dual-monitors-and-full-screen-mode?s=4487c77024f94723b8f3774ca0a99a63), this was added in Yosemite if the windows are on separate monitors. Great!

Is there any keyboard shortcut that switches between full-screen windows on a single monitor?

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the set of keyboard shortcuts with the addition of @soulshined's input:

- If I have two windows from *different* apps I can switch with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
- If I have two windows from *the same* app I can switch with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>.
- If I have two *full-screen windows* from the same app then <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> doesn’t work, but I can switch with <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> (or <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>; I chose <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> to
  avoid conflict with browser back/forward shortcuts).
- If I have two full-screen windows from the same app *on different
  monitors* then <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> doesn’t work but <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> does.
- If I have two full-screen windows from the same app on different
  monitors *and the target window is currently not in front* then <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> both fail to work. I have to <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to another app that is on the target monitor, then <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>  to the target window. *Correction*: <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> scrolls through spaces on the ***original*** monitor, not the target monitor, so there's actually no way to do this that I know of.

Aside: if I enable the keyboard shortcuts for “Switch to Desktop 1” and “Switch to Desktop 2” and use two monitors, the shortcuts won’t work if the specified desktop is not assigned to the current monitor.

I've entered a usability bug with Apple, number 19363102.

Comment: Oh my god, this is stupid. I work in full screen mode 90% of the time and very often have the need to switch between different instances of the same app. It makes no sense to disable the _Cmd-`_ shortcut, just because a window is in full screen mode, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I have outlined below what you should do. In short, ***yes*** it is possible, because I use it everyday

1. Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → 'Shortcuts' tab.
2. Click on the 'Mission Control' option in the left sidebar.
3. Now on the right sidebar you will see a Mission Control heading with a disclosure triangle next to it. Click on the triangle to show additional options.
4. You will see predefined options for you to select from; however, the keyboard shortcuts can be edited as necessary. I have mine set to <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> to switch between spaces.

Visual aid:
[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Shortcuts preferences with steps labeled]

**If this doesn't work for you, it's because you don't have your displays segregated.** If you're running more than one monitor:

- Go to System Settings > Mission Control and check 'Displays have separate Spaces'.
- You will have to log out and log back in for it to take effect.

Additionally, for further desktop organization you can set your apps to only appear on a certain window or space, so that way that application only populates in the space you designate. You can do this by going to System Preferences → Mission Control and check "Group windows by application" so there isn't cluttering of applications.

**NOTE**

This is not OS specific (works with Mavericks or Yosemite) and is not prejudiced to full screen apps. In other words, since you're switching spaces it doesn't matter what's in the space or how it's displayed; it will switch regardless. Lastly, it functions regardless of your screen output, setup, or format. I have three monitors and it only affects the active display.

Comment: Great suggestion, @soulshined.

Comment: @AshleyG  Thanks. It doesn't emulate the command but if both windows of the same application are full screen and in different spaces it essentially emulates the effect.

Comment: Exploring this a bit more I've found a situation where I can't get a window visible using keyboard shortcuts. I've summarized everything in a new answer as comments don't allow the length and formatting required.